# Angular redirecting to otherwise without detecting view but it works when i click back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Update**
None of the answers or comments below help at all, I wish someone would give me the correct answer.

When I put this url below in my browser - it takes me my fruits view and works perfectly,

```
http://localhost:53052/AppTest.aspx#/fruits
```

BUT when I go to my `home view` and click on button and try to navigate to `'fruits'` view then it redirects me to `http://localhost:53052/AppTest.aspx#/routeNotFound`

## BUT when I click on browser's back button it goes back to fruits view then if I click again then it goes back to home view.

So here is what happens in tree view,

--> Click on Home view button (should navigate to `fruits view` but it goes to `routeNotFound` view instead)

--> When I click on back button on browser, it goes to `fruits view`, then if I click back again then it goes to `Home view`

Here is my routes,

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('fruitApp');
    app.constant('routes', getRoutes());
    app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);

    function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, routes) {
        routes.forEach(function (route) {
            $routeProvider.when(route.url, route.config);
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/routeNotFound' });
    }

    function getRoutes() {
        return [
          {
              url: '/home',
              config: {
                  templateUrl: 'App/templates/home.html',
              }
          },
          {
              url: '/fruits',
              config: {
                  templateUrl: 'App/templates/fruits.html',
              }
          }
        ];
    }
})();
```

Main View (I only use it for loading modules and loading other views into it)

```
   <div data-ng-app="fruitApp">
        <div data-ng-view="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Home View

```
<div data-ng-controller="home as vm">
     <div data-ng-click="vm.goToFruits()">click Me!</div>
</div>
```

Home Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = "home";
    angular.module('fruitApp').controller(controllerId,
        ['$location', 'datacontext', home]);

    function home($location, datacontext) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.goToFruits = goToFruits;

        function goToFruits() {
            $location.path('/fruits');
        }
    };
})();
```

Fruits View

```
<div data-ng-controller="fruits as vm"> fruits </div>
```

Fruit Controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var controllerId = "fruits";
    angular.module('fruitApp').controller(controllerId,
        ['$location', 'datacontext', fruits]);

    function fruits($location, datacontext) {
        var vm = this;
    };
})();
```

I am following this project so defining module like I do shouldn't be an issue if I am not missing any concept ?

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Learning-Path-Manager-Code-Sample/blob/master/App/learningPath/learningPaths.js

**Edit**

I tried change route config and some code in controller to use `ui-route` instead now it takes me to the fruits view (as it was doing before) but it's not redirecting me to 'otherwise' route anymore BUT it is still changing the URL to `/routeNotFound`..

**Update**

I ended up using href and ng-href for switching views.

Comment: What's the URL on the 404 page?

Comment: http://localhost:53052/AppTest.aspx#/routeNotFound

Comment: Have you posted the right controller in the example?  That looks like the fruits controller not home.

Comment: @DoctorMick sorry it was typo, I updated it

Comment: You could try to listen on $routeChangeStart and $routeChangeSuccess to try in more debugging.

Comment: @Okazari I am pretty new to angularjs, I am google how to use $routeChangeStart now, thanks :)

Comment: Also, you probably shoudn't use "data-ng-controller" in your view, since you're using the router. (You already made the mapping with the "controller" property of your route)

Comment: If you can see the page via URL access then the problem should be in 'click()' event. normally links should start with #, so you can try  $location.path('#/fruits'); in goToFruits()

Comment: @afsinka https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#path

Comment: Works fine in a plunker, maybe your http server do something ? http://plnkr.co/edit/fvB1f36sDAn01bPVYTrA?p=preview

Comment: @Okazari I must be missing some concept but it's not showing anything when I go to plunker, I mean there is nothing in preview or url is not changing as well

Comment: My bad, i updated the plunker. You will not see the url change as you're actually inside a plunked. But you will see that the routing is working as expected. (The view will switch)

Comment: remove the controller inside getRoutes() => config. As you defined the controller twice...one inside route i.e. getRoutes() and other on partial. Due to that it will be hitting the controller twice and in the second it might be going into some problem

Comment: I can recommend the angular ui-router, its way better than the original - just as a FYI

Comment: Can you try put a a tag with href="#/fruits" to see what happens ?

Comment: @Walfrat I tried and now it doesn't goes to fruits controller at all, but just goes to otherwise

Comment: @SimonPertersen I followed your advise, now when I click on go to fruits and it successfully takes me to the view (and doesn't redirects me to the otherwise route), but URL still goes to /routeNotFound for some weird reason

Comment: @PleaseTeach sounds weird, the syntax is: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/'); and then set a url path - iv'd used it in this old project of mine: https://github.com/sp90/prototype-builder/blob/master/app/js/app.js you can checkout my config??

Comment: @SimonPertersen you can change otherwise to anything or any other view you want, it doesn't have to be '/' :)

Comment: I know but @PleaseTeach it was just to note that it has to be the url and not the state name

Comment: @SimonPertersen thanks for the information but it's not related to problem I am facing at the moment :( sorry but feel really frustrated...

Comment: @Okazari 's plunker work fine for me. The # is not required for $location.path. As your question also concern the behavior of the browser's back button, may I also ask you which browser are you using ?

Answer (score 5):

You've got a lot of 'fluff' in your example there. I've stripped a bit of it out and you should be able to see the [plunkr demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/40eDlZfZQnAJRWxeg1ge) - it helps to see if you run it without the frame - http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/40eDlZfZQnAJRWxeg1ge/# .

For me it looks like it works just fine. I can click the text to navigate to "fruits" controller, and I hit the 'back' button in the browser to go back to 'home'.

A few things about your code:

1. Your app.module needed to be declared with `app.module('fruitsApp', ['ngRoute']);` to ensure the dependencies are loaded.
2. I removed the 'datacontext' etc that your example code doesn't need to know about
3. I'm using basic templates rather than templateUrls in the routes.
4. I made the default route redirect to `'/home'` - does this make sense in your context?

My advice for you is to remove pieces of your code until it starts to work, then use this to figure out what exactly is causing the problems.

Comment: 1st point is I think just a typo mistake, but I am yet to figure out what's wrong with my code when run on my browser, I still didn't got a chance to test your changes in different files but I will award you bounty as otherwise it will expire, thanks

Comment: Awesome thanks! Ping me in chat if you need more feedback.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to go simple , first make skeleton of your application with function routing and and required dependencies later on extend and enhance. 
one big mistake you have done is that you haven't  included '**ngRoute**' in your **fruitApp**. working example you can check on this plunker [ng-routing example](http://plnkr.co/edit/7AATv1WoN1OQFwWRL3KC?p=preview/)

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('fruitsApp', ['ngRoute']);
    app.constant('routes', getRoutes());
    app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routes', routeConfigurator]);

    function routeConfigurator($routeProvider, routes) {
        routes.forEach(function (route) {
            $routeProvider.when(route.url, route.config);
        });
        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
    }

    function getRoutes() {
        return [
          {
              url: '/home',
              config: {
                  templateUrl: 'home.html',
                  controller:'home'
              }
          },
          {
              url: '/fruits',
              config: {
                  templateUrl: 'fruit.html',
                  controller:'fruits'
              }
          }
        ];
    }

    app.controller("home", ['$location',
      function($location) {
          this.goToFruits = function() {
              $location.path('/fruits');
          };
      }
    ]);

    app.controller("fruits", ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams','$location', 
      function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {

        $scope.fruitList = [
          {name:'Apple'},
          {name:'Apricot'},
          {name:'Banana'},
          {name:'Banana'},
          {name:'Bilberry'},
          {name:'Blackberry'} ];

          $scope.goBackHome= function(){
             $location.path('/home');
          };

      }
    ]);

})();
```